# Tense for habit with unfinished time period

Tags: present-perfect

"I have watched TV twice a week this year."
And
"I have been watching TV twice a week this year."

What is the difference between the sentences above? Can they mean the same? Is either of them not correct?

Comment: The *continuous* version is the ***normal*** way of expressing the ***normal*** meaning (watching TV twice a week is something I have been doing throughout this year, with the very likely additional implication that I expect to ***continue*** doing so). If a competent native speaker chose *not* to use the continuous form, I'd probably try to think of some slightly different intended meaning (perhaps there was only a single week earlier this year when the speaker watched TV twice in one week, but that was remarkable because he had never done this before).

Comment: (Having said that, they *can* mean the same, and if a *non-native speaker* used the non-continuous form I'd simply assume the more common meaning anyway.)

Comment: Thanks, FumbleFingers, for an answer.I'm not sure I understand, though. I am interested only in correct grammatical use of the sentences by very competent native English speakers. Do both sentences mean the same or the one with simple perfect mean what you suggested?

Comment: Words don't usually have a precise meaning *without a specific context*. As I said, if someone like *you* said to me "I have watched TV twice a week this year," I would almost certainly assume the "normal" meaning. But I might make the same assumption if I was talking to a native speaker - especially if I didn't think they were very "good with words". Besides, there are many subtle factors that might affect things - even just a *slight* stress on the word ***have*** in your "non-continuous" version would almost certainly be enough to force the "only in one week, or very rarely" interpretation.

Comment: (That's to say, both versions are "grammatically **perfect**", and in many contexts no-one would understand them as meaning anything different. It's primarily a stylistic choice.)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for help.